# Jquery, how to add hidden elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add is-hidden at **here**

```
<span class="tag is-danger is-rounded is-small is-bolded span_notif_count ... "></span>
```

but I don't know how to use jquery, can someone help me? this my first-time use jquery

Comment: $('span.tag').addClass("is-hidden")

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4642212). _“but I don't know how to use jquery”_ — asking questions is the least efficient way to learn jQuery. Just read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) or [guide](https://learn.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the code below:

```js
$('span.tag').addClass("is-hidden")

console.log($('span').attr('class'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="tag is-danger is-rounded is-small is-bolded span_notif_count "></span>
```

Example with if condition:

```js
if ($('span').attr('class').length > 0) {
  $('span.tag').addClass("is-hidden");
  console.log($('span').attr('class'));
} else {
  console.log("there is no span class");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="tag is-danger is-rounded is-small is-bolded span_notif_count "></span>
```

Comment: how i can do it with if condition? sry this my first using jqueary ajax

Comment: I updated my answer with a generic if condition. JQuery is very similar to JS, just simplified. If this helps, please upvote . Thanks!